# Using Numpy arrayobjects in Visual Studio C++. Converting C++ array type to numpy array type

Tags: python, c++, numpy, visual-c++, cython

I want to include numpy/arrayobject.h in visual studio VC++
and then create a function that accepts two numpy type array and perform matrix multiplication between those array.

Problem is that does not seem to work.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    import_array();

    // Declare and initialize an array to store your data
    int data[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        data[i] = i;
    }

    npy_intp dims[1] = { 5 };
    PyObject* pArray = PyArray_SimpleNew(1, dims, NPY_INT);

    // Populate the NumPy array with your data
    int* array_data = (int*)PyArray_DATA((PyArrayObject*)pArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        array_data[i] = data[i];
    }

    PyObject* pValue = Py_BuildValue("i", 2);
    PyObject* pArgs = PyTuple_Pack(2, pArray, pValue);
    PyObject* pResult = PyObject_CallObject((PyObject*)&PyArray_Type, pArgs);

    Py_DECREF(pArgs);
    Py_DECREF(pArray);

    int* result_data = (int*)PyArray_DATA((PyArrayObject*)pResult);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << result_data[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    Py_DECREF(pResult);
    Py_DECREF(pValue);
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Also, I don't see any attempt to do matrix multiplication in your code. What is the purpose of that line: `PyObject_CallObject((PyObject*)&PyArray_Type, pArgs);` ? You want to call `np.array` constructor with a tuple of `(another_array, 2)` ?